Prevent (whats)app from bypassing system silent mode?
If if my (OnePlus 6T) phone is on silent mode, messages on whatsapp trigger a vibrating notification. How can I prevent that?
Is that something I should configure in the (whats) app settings, or the system -> Apps & Notifications part? In the whatsApp Notifications settings, I have Vibrate: default, which I thought would follow the system's default, but that doesn't seem to be the case?
This is Whatsapp 2.24.9.78 on Android 11.1.2.2

I think it's a Oneplus issue. See similar report and here
